# Electron app not showing on-screen keyboard on windows

Tags: windows, electron

I have an electron app made for windows computer with touchscreen.
It is basically only a webview loading a website.

If I open the website on chrome and touch a text input, it always show the on-screen keyboard.

If I open my app by clicking on it, it never show the on-screen keyboard.

And if I open my app by touching it, the first touch on a text input show the on-screen keyboard. But the following touches only show the keyboard when the input is losing the focus (instead of when gaining it).

I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Tell me if you need to see a part of my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from the webview. I modified my app to load the url directly from a BrowserWindow instead of a webview and it is working perfectly.